# Update method attributes during JIT?

Tags: c++, .net, jit, cil

I am looking for the method to update the attributes of an existing method without creating a new method definition.

Here is the code which I have so far:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Weaver::JITCompilationStarted( 
        FunctionID functionId, BOOL fIsSafeToBlock) 
{
    HRESULT status = S_OK;
    MethodInfo methodInfo = GetMethodInfo(functionId);
    if (!IsMdVirtual(methodInfo.Attributes) && !IsMdStatic(methodInfo.Attributes)
        && !IsMdPrivate(methodInfo.Attributes) && !IsMdSpecialName(methodInfo.Attributes))
    {
        CComPtr<IMetaDataEmit> metaDataEmit;
        status = m_profilerInfo3->GetModuleMetaData(methodInfo.Module,
            ofRead | ofWrite, IID_IMetaDataEmit, (IUnknown**)&metaDataEmit);

        // TODO: get module metadata and update method attributes to:  methodInfo.Attributes | mdVirtual
        status = metaDataEmit->ApplyEditAndContinue(metaDataEmit /*?*/);
    }

    return status;
}
```

As you can see, I am missing the methods to retrieve the function metadata and modify in-line. MSDN help on this method is very thin, and could not find any examples of the usage of `ApplyEditAndContinue`.

Comment: I vote to have mandatory comment for any (or at least the first) down-votes... saves us noobs trying to figure out why.

Comment: JITCompilationStarted is way too late to change attributes, the attributes could be inspected well before the method is ever called or JIT'ed. Metadata can only be modified from the [ModuleLoadFinished](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230105%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) callback. Why would you want to use ApplyEditAndContinue to add attributes rather than DefineCustomAttribute? What are you actually trying to achieve. (and no, I'm not the one who down voted)

Comment: @BrianReichle, thanks for the heads-up, Basically I want to mutate regular class methods to be virtual methods so they can be mocked during unit tests. This means I need to change an existing attribute. Basically non virtual methods is the most common reason for difficulty of unit testing our legacy code. And I would like to avoid modifying the assemblies on disk (eg via [Fody's](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) [Virtuosity](https://github.com/Fody/Virtuosity))

Comment: Ah, then maybe you use [SetMethodProps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set [mdVirtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231030%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in dwMethodFlags.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Brian's answer in the comments:

> JITCompilationStarted is way too late to change attributes, the attributes could  be inspected well before the method is ever called or JIT'ed. Metadata can only be modified from the ModuleLoadFinished callback.

Which translates to code along the lines of (heavily reduced):

```
HRESULT Weaver::ModuleLoadFinished(ModuleID moduleId, HRESULT hrStatus)
{
    HRESULT status = S_OK;
    // Filter module

    // Enum & filter types in module
        // Enum & filter methods in type
            DWORD attributes, implFlags; ULONG codeRva;
            status = pMetaImport->GetMethodProps(tkMethod, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &attributes, NULL, NULL, &codeRva, &implFlags);
            status = pMetaEmit->SetMethodProps(tkMethod, attributes | mdVirtual, codeRva, implFlags);

    return status;
}
```

This will allow for mocking non-virtual members in .NET Eg:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Hello() => "test";
}

// ...
var fake = A.Fake<Foo>();
A.CallTo(() => fake.Hello()).Returns("faked");
Assert.Equals("faked", fake.Hello());
```